# Clojure spec.alpha - How to (reference another argument) / (describe that argument collection should include values from another argument collection)

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

What I need:
a spec for a function, that has two arguments:

- a hash-map of keywords and strings.
- a vector that may have strings or keywords **but** if it is a keyword **it must exist inside hash-map** (first argument)

**(your answer doesn't have to cover all of this, mainly I need a way to tell that if it is a keyword it must exist in hash-map)**

Here is what I have:

(this is an example to show that it is possible to access both arguments inside :args, I know that it doesn't test anything and always fails because nil is returned)

```
(ns my-example.core
  (:require
   [clojure.spec.alpha :as spec]))

(defn my-example [m v] nil)

(spec/fdef my-example
  :args (fn [[m v]] nil))
```

This fn kind of works (it is possible to create a function that would work how I want), But it isn't very descriptive and when it fails (given that there is `` (stest/instrument `my-example)) `` it just shows me body of function (like this: `(fn [[m v]] nil)`).

Is this the only way to solve my problem or there is a better way?

I also tryed to define a spec and use it inside :args :

```
(spec/def :my-example/my-check (fn [[m v]] nil))

(spec/fdef my-example
  :args :my-example/my-check)
```

But result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spec for `:args`, you can specify any predicate you want.  See the example provided at the [spec guide for fdef](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_specing_functions).  Given that example, here is a code fragment that mostly works for your case.  I say "mostly" because the spec for the first map argument could be made stricter to note that it is a map of keywords to strings.  The forms inside the `comment` form show some usage examples.

```clj
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest]))

(defn my-example [m v] nil)

(s/fdef my-example
  :args (s/and (s/cat :m map? :v vector?)
               #(every? (fn [x] (or (string? x)
                                    (and (keyword? x)
                                         (contains? (:m %) x))))
                        (:v %)))
  :ret nil?)

(comment
  (stest/instrument `my-example)
  (my-example {:a "a" :b "b"} ["foo" :a "bar" :b]) ; => nil
  (my-example {:a "a" :b "b"} ["foo" :a "bar" :c]) ; => spec exception
  (my-example {:a "a" :b "b"} ["foo" :a "bar" 2]) ; => spec exception
  )
```

Comment: Thank you that works, I also found out that it is possible to do `(def my-check? #(every? (fn [x] (or (string? x)
                                   (and (keyword? x)
                                        (contains? (:m %) x))))
                       (:v %)))` and this way when it fails it would show name of function instead of it's body which is easier to comprehend (if name is descriptive)

Comment: defining it as a spec also works, is it better to define it as a spec?

Comment: Correct.  Using a named function will make the error message more localized.

Comment: I don't think making the `my-check?` predicate into a spec is useful. A spec is typically for one data structure, whereas `my-check?` is a predicate over two data structures.